# How to group and count in haskell?

Tags: haskell

Given a list (for instance `[1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6]`) how is it possible to group and count them according to bins/range? I would like to be able to specify a range, so that:

Say range=2, and using the previous list, would give me `[1, 4, 2, 1]`, given that there's 1 0's or 1's, 4 2's or 3's, 2 4's or 5's and 1 6's or 7's.

Say range=4, and using the previous list, would give me [5, 3], given that there's 5 0's or 1's or 2's or 3's, 3 4's or 5's or 6's or 7's.

I have looked into `group` and `groupBy` but not found appropriate predicates, and also the histogram-fill library. The latter seems very nice to create bins, but I could not find out how to load data into those bins.

How can I achieve this?

My attempt on one of the suggestions below:

```
import Data.List 
import Data.Function 

quantize range n = n `div` range  

main = print (groupBy ((==) `on` quantize 4) [1,2,3,4,2])
```

The output is [[1,2,3],[4],[2]] when it should have been [[1,2,2,3],[4]]. Both suggestions below works on sorted lists.

```
main = print (groupBy ((==) `on` quantize 4) (sort [1,2,3,4,2]))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to quantize in order to get the definitions of the bins.

```
-- `quantize range n` rounds n down to the nearest multiple of range
quantize :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

`groupBy` takes a "predicate" argument*, which identifies whether two items should be placed in the same bin.  So:

```
groupBy (\n m -> quantize range n == quantize range m) :: [Int] -> [[Int]]
```

will group elements by whether they are in the same bin, without changing the elements.  If `range` is 2, that will give you something like

```
[[1],[2,2,3,3],[4,5],[6]]
```

Then you just have to take the `length` of each sublist.

*** There's a neat function called [`on`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on) which allows you to write the predicate more succinctly

```
groupBy ((==) `on` quantize range)
```

Comment: quantize is defined in a library?

Comment: No, it's left as exercise.

Comment: ahh, ok. just wondered. It seems that "div" in the above post will be a nice clue to this.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this using the `groupBy` and `div` functions. Let's say we have a range `N`. If we get the integral division (`div`) of `N` consecutive numbers, all of those should be equal. For example, `N=3`, `0 div 3 = 0, 1 div 3 = 0, 2 div 3 = 0, 3 div 3 = 1, 4 div 3 = 1, 5 div 3 = 1, 6 div 3 = 2`.

Knowing this, we can look at `groupBy :: (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]` and use the function:

```
sameGroup :: Integral a => a -> a -> a -> Bool
sameGroup range a b = a `div` range == b `div` range
```

To write our own grouping function

```
groupings :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [[a]]
groupings range = groupBy (sameGroup range)
```

Which should look something like `groupings 2 [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6] == [[1], [2, 2, 3, 3], [4, 5], [6]]`. Now we just have to count it to have the final function

```
groupAndCount :: Integral a => a -> [a] -> [Int]
groupAndCount range list = map length $ groupings range list
```

Which should mirror the wanted behavior.

Comment: thank you both of you for really good and thorough answers without any comment about the simple nature of my question (I am new to haskell). I will select an answer (I think both are valid) tomorrow.

Comment: I need to try out Mephys answer as I am not so used to $ (I thought I would need to declare groupings as taking two arguments as it stands now).

Comment: @hotGopher This is called [point-free style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Point-free).